# Car plate recognition from video using python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tensorflow, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0b8j.png)I am running this code but it has given an error which I am trying to solve.
The given code is of car plate recognition from video written in python.

The given error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Main.py", line 16, in
<module>
     plate_Original, plate_morphEx, edge = preprocessOne(plateFrame, (42,10), True)   File
 "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Radar\pythonEdition\Modules\Basic.py", line
 11, in preprocessOne
     plateGray = enhance(cv2.cvtColor(plateFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2)
 C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
 error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
 'cv::cvtColor'
```

In Main.py:-

```
    plate_Original, plate_morphEx, edge = preprocessOne(plateFrame, (42,10), True)
```

In Basic.py:-

```
def preprocessOne(plateFrame, se_shape, Show = False):
plateOrigin = copy.copy(plateFrame)
plateGray = enhance(cv2.cvtColor(plateFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
plateGaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(plateGray, (5,5), 0)
plateSobel = cv2.Sobel(plateGaussian, -1, 1, 0)
h, plateThresh = cv2.threshold(plateSobel, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

se = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, se_shape)
plateMorphEx = cv2.morphologyEx(plateThresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)
edge = np.copy(plateThresh)
```

Comment: As told by others, usually that means that the file is missing or (more probably) the filepath is wrong. Try to manually put the absolute file path and report the result back.

Answer (score 2):

`src.empty()` in function `cv::cvtColor` usually means that the input file is missing. Check the path and content of the video file. Or maybe there is a problem with plateFrame in `main.py`. Try printing plateFrame and its shape.

Comment: well i ahave tried to print the value and its shape of plateFrame and I got the values of it But can't figure out the error

Comment: Can you post the output that you are getting?

Comment: ok I have posted image output which is getting on top of the question

Comment: That is the result of `print(plateFrame)`? Inside `preprocessOne` or in the `main`? Your error is in `Basic.py` which means `plateFrame` is not getting passed on to the `cv2.cvtColor` function in `Basic.py`.

Comment: This was the result of print(plateFrame) and also shape of it inside the Main.py